# Error when distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox

Tags: ios, url-scheme, app-distribution

I am using dropbox for distributing my addhoc builds over the air.Till last week it was working all fine.From this week the html page does not open in safari browser in iphone. Instead it is showing following message [image]

One more thing i would like to mention is i have an app called iZip installed on my test device.So open with iZip option pops up for opening it in iZip,but when I do that the html file loads fine.I searched for this issue but didn't found any solution yet.I also found out that since iOS 9 apple has made changes in opening url schemes.So would that be a problem or some more additional things we need to add.I am testing this on iOS8 and iOS9

Answer (score 3):

I just found out a sad news from this url [Discontinuing rendering of HTML content](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208778663-Discontinuing-rendering-of-HTML-content)
that dropbox has dropped the support of rendering html file content in browser.So have to look for another way to deploy my build over the air.

**Update 1**

I have found workaround in which HTML page wont be rendered but still your build will get downloaded successfully.So here is what we have to do now

In our html file we have code like this
`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9pj4sds3r9k4nlmn/testApp.plist`

copy whole thing and paste it in web browser,pop up will appear saying **"Open this page in App Store"?** just say open and after 4-5 second another pop up saying **"dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to instal .app"** so click install and build will get installed.

Comment: Yes, I was very depressed to discover this too

Comment: @AlexBauer I have found a workaround, you can refer my updated answer.

Comment: Still it's downloading index.html ;(

Comment: @Jack when I tried this approach, I also faced some issue as this is just a workaround.It's not a foolproof solution.Maybe you can try some third party options like this website https://www.diawi.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL your are using in your browser is the URL to download the HTML file ( due to dl.dropbox ... )

You should find an other url that let user display it ( look for `share link` )